# Rspec appears to be missing the expect method ... is this correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm running my rspec tests and it's outputting the following:

```
Failure/Error: expect {
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:44:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The line that the error is referencing is the line where it says "expect {".  I'm not quite sure what on earth is going wrong here.

Here is the full spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  def valid_attributes
      {
      :username => "tester",
      :email => "tester@holler.com",
      :password => "testingpass"
      }
  end

  def valid_session
    {}
  end

  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new User" do
        expect {
          post :create, {:user => valid_attributes , :format => :json}, valid_session
        }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

**Update**

A commenter asked for the spec_helper.rb file.  I'm posting it below ... it's the default one generated by rspec.

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

Comment: This works fine for me.  Can we see any relevant parts of `user.rb` and `spec_helper.rb`?

Comment: The problem definitely isn't with user.rb as I just ran the project and it creates and deletes a user perfectly fine.  I'm posting an update with spec_helper.rb which happens to be the auto-generated version

Comment: Did you make any changes to `user.rb` or `users_controller.rb`?  That would be the next place to look.

Comment: There are no changes.  Why would we check there anyways when that's not the error being reported?

Comment: Well, when I run your spec with the autogenerated model, controller, and rspec_helper, it runs fine.  What files have you made changes to?

Comment: Try removing the `expect` block and just run the `post :create`, see if that error message is more helpful.

Comment: Thanks zetetic, that helped me diagnose the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's not missing the `expect` method - the failure message says it's missing `[]` on `nil`. By default, RSpec only shows you the line *in the spec* that leads to the problem, but sometimes the problem is deeper down.

Run the spec with the `--backtrace` flag on the command line to see the full backtrace and pinpoint the real source.

HTH,
David